# call db.loadServerScripts on connection startup

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some [server-side helper functions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) in system.js collection, which are then used in node.js. However sometimes, they are undefined.

Here is the scenario:
I load these functions once, on server start:

```
db.eval('db.loadServerScripts()', function(err, result) { ... });
```

So this is called only once on start, not for every request.

From now on I can call e.g.:

```
db.eval('getNextSequence(\'test\')', function(err, seq){});
```

But sometimes I get the error, that getNextSequence is undefined. I suspect those functions to exist only in current connection scope. So maybe when node receives new connection, the functions are not set.

Is there any way to use those functions in node.js, but to have them reliably available always?

---

Example scenario:

```
//1./ this function is stored in system.js
getNextSequence: function(name) 
{
    var ret = db.counters.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: name },
        update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        new: true,
        upsert: true
    });
    return ret ? ret.seq : null;
}

//2./ this is called on nodejs server startup (once for server lifetime)
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", {native_parser:true});
//...
db.eval('db.loadServerScripts()', function(err, result) {
    //...crash if failed
}); 

//3./ this is used in node.js code, on request processing:
db.eval('getNextSequence(\'someNamespace\')', function(err, seq){
    // int seq is converted to string slug
    // a new entity with slugId is saved to collection
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you use these functions? [`db.loadServerScripts`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.loadServerScripts/) loads functions from the `system.js` collection into the mongo shell. To use them server-side, for example in `db.eval`, you shouldn't need to call `db.loadServerScripts` at all. I think this is only a shell function, but you are talking about using it in Node, can you clarify? Are you using the shell or the node driver to interface with MongoDB?

Comment: wdberkeley: thanks for reaction, I tried to reformulate the question.

Comment: `db.loadServerScripts` is for loading the server side js into the current mongo shell session. I don't think it makes sense to call it in `db.eval`. `system.js` functions should be defined in eval anyway. The most likely reason for your undefined errors is that the the function is out of scope because your `db.eval` is being run on another database. Also, node != mongo shell. You are using the mongo shell, or node?

Comment: I understand Your point. In this scenario, I am using only node.js, no mongo shell. The functions are persisted in system.js collection and loaded by node.js via db.eval('db.loadServerScripts()', ...) on server startup. Then I have tenth of succesfull request, that are using those functions  till evantually one request fails with undefined function call. I think, that the functions are loaded in connection scope and when the connection is terminated and node receives a new one, it fails. So I am looking for a way how to initialize every new connection (if my gues is right).

Comment: I would prefer to not to call db.eval('db.loadServerScripts()', ...) in every request, sinc it is high load service and I am trying to make as few db calls as possible.

Comment: Can I see what the code using these evals looks like? It's clear there's some misunderstanding here of how `eval`, etc. work and I think the easiest path forward is for me to be able to see what you're actually trying to accomplish and then explain in those terms.

Comment: @wdberkeley: thanks for patience :). Please look at simplified scenario at the end of question.